# Where is the documentation for mixing DFS-R between Windows 2012 and Windows 2012 R2?

Tags: dfs-r

First question - is it possible to use DFS-R between an original Windows 2012 server and a newer Windows 2012 R2 server?

Second question - R2 introduces many enhancements in DFS-R, one assumes these aren't available until all servers in the mesh are on R2?

Comment: This is totally a "what does the documentation say" question.

Comment: Title changed...

Comment: better! hopefully someone from experience can chime in, I was not able to find anything on my first google-fu pass, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. While there is some functionality differences between the OS editions, they are compatible.
2. Not necessarily. Features like cloning require the source and destination to be 2012 R2. But not all replica set members need be 2012 R2.

Naturally, the full benefits of the latest version of DFSR in any OS (including 2012 R2) are realised when the full replica set is running the latest OS.